# Python: Find and Print strings, multiple instances per line

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, data-analysis

Im not finding an answer to my exact question and unable to relate similar to it as well.
Here is what i have:

```
file = input('put file name here: ')

try:
        fhand = open(file)

        for line in fhand:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if line.find('[') == -1: continue
                atpos1 = line.find('[')
                atpos2 = line.find(']')
                info = line[atpos1+1:atpos2]

                print(info)
except:
        print('incorrect file name')

print('you are done')
quit()
```

this works great for the first instance of a string between the brakets, but there are multiple instances per line at times. How do I print every occurance of a word/string that falls between brackets in my document?

Comment: try giving it a name thats not there. Crash ensured.

Comment: I fixed that. my question is below the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [str.find(sub[, start[, end]])](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and proide the `start` value after the last found `']'` for a new search - put it into a while loop until no more `'['` are found:

```
file = "t.txt"

with open(file,"w") as f:
    f.write("""nothing
some [one] some
some [one] some [two] more [three] things
some [one] some""")


try:
    with open(file) as f:
        for idx, line in enumerate(f,1):
            line = line.rstrip()
            pos = line.find('[')           # store first position
            while pos != -1:               # only continue if found
                atpos2 = line.find(']', pos)   # find end after pos
                info = line[pos+1:atpos2]      # get part

                pos = line.find('[',atpos2)    # find next start after end
                print(f"Found '{info}' in line {idx}") 
except Exception as e:  # maybe print the error as well...
        print('stop being a stupid', e)


print('you are done')
```

Output:

```
Found 'one' in line 2
Found 'one' in line 3
Found 'two' in line 3
Found 'three' in line 3
Found 'one' in line 4
you are done
```

The part `atpos2 = line.find(']', pos)   # find end after pos` is important for string like

```
'this ] will give you [weird] outputs [ elsewise'
```

Comment: Thank you! a bit above my skill level, but that's good. I'm trying to learn and this helps a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can continue to look for brackets until no bracket is left like this:

```
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    while line.find('[') != -1:
        atpos1 = line.find('[')
        atpos2 = line.find(']')
        info = line[atpos1+1:atpos2]
        line = line[atpos2:len(line)]
        print(info)
```

Comment: would work - but why do you slice the line? this creates a new throwaway string.... simply using the find with a second parameter where to start the search is cleaner. see above. You also search twice for each [ ' s position  once in the while and then to get the posistion for the slicing